# Microsoft Graph Repeatedly Returning 503 / 504 Errors On Requests For Some Users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When using the Graph API I have noticed that specific users in my tenants receive 503 errors (sometimes 504 errors, but more rarely). There doesn't necessarily seem to be any rhyme or reason to these errors, dozens of users can be fine but one specific user might have failing requests for their calendar for example. The example response below is for mail, but I've also seen it for calendar (very common) and sometimes OneDrive as well.

```
    com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphFatalServiceException: Unexpected exception returned from the service.Error code: UnknownError
    Error message: Error while processing response.

    GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/REDACTED/mailFolders/REDACTED
    Prefer : odata.maxpagesize=200
    SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.3.2
    Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]


    503 : Service Unavailable
    [...]
```

On the surface, this appears to potentially be related to some sort of throttling, however, throttling tends to be intermittent - in this case it is a persistent behavior for certain users. There doesn't seem to be a strong correlation between the size of the resource and this behavior. Furthermore, this behavior happens deterministically for some users - especially for calendars. I've noticed that requests for some users have been failing for weeks due to these errors.

Backing off and trying again later does not appear to help, even after waiting 10 + minutes. It's also strange that larger users in the same tenant often do not exhibit this same behavior. Even more strange, some users that have this problem their mailbox doesn't receive these errors but their calendar does (and vice versa).

What are the best practices around dealing with these errors (besides backing off and try again) and is this expected behavior? Are there some potential explanations that explain why some users experience it but not others?

Comment: This seems pretty specific to me: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling)

Comment: The throttling documentation is already well known to me. Throttling is intermittent typically, however, in this case specific users persistently experience these 503 errors.

Comment: (1) Do you have the detailed error response? If yes share it, also make sure you have the requestid, timestamp for it. (2) Also what happens if you do retry the API call?

Comment: do you have any updates?

Comment: @Dev I was able to reproduce this just now in the graph explorer and I believe I have discovered the root cause. For whatever reason, for some users a larger page size results in a 503 error. I generally use a page size of 200 and it works fine, however, in this case it always results in a 503 (including in graph explorer). When I reduce page size to 100, it works fine.

"date": "2020-12-09T14:18:17",
"request-id": "de9a7a29-a503-4ffa-806c-1d472b9faa36",

Comment: @Dev Do you have any updates?

Comment: Unfortunately not much info available. Being said that sharing my views/suggestions: (1) In general if they see HTTP 503 then in short its telling that the server is unavailable at the given point of time, when the call is made. Also the service is temporarily unavailable for maintenance or is overloaded (2) Why some users get and some don't get - it may have various reasons. For example, their mailboxes are located in different datacenters or GEO (3) Best practices - you may repeat the request after a delay, the length of which may be specified in a Retry-After header!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of July 2021 this bug still exists in the Graph API. For some reason, some users tend to produce these 5xx series errors no matter which endpoints I've used or combinations of query parameters. The only working solution I've come across is to fall back to the [legacy EWS sdk](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api) and utilize the delta mechanism it provides instead of the Graph API mechanism. This always seems to work and does not suffer from the same problem, and the data retrieval can still be done with Graph (it's only the delta that is broken).